# In TCL,l open a file from the tail

Tags: performance, file, tcl

I have this issue:
I need sometimes to process huge text files.
In some cases, I know that the data I care about is in the tail of the file. If I use normal open, I need to scroll through the lines. Is there a way to "start from the end", and save time, maybe read the file backwards?

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll through"? Do you literally mean using the mouse/arrow keys to scroll or do you mean read the file line by line?

Comment: Check out the [`seek`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/seek.htm) command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `seek` command:

```
set linesz 256 ; # assume an approximate line size
set fh [open myfile.txt]
seek $fh [expr {$linesz*-5}] end
gets $fh line ; # this first line is probably a partial line, ignore it.
while { [gets $fh line] >= 0 } {
   # process
}
close $fh
```

References: [seek](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/seek.htm)

Comment: The only complications with this approach are working out that guess for the line length, and the number of lines to go back (`-5`). Getting good values for them requires knowing the data.

Comment: If the data line length is highly variable or knowledge of the data is sparse, the line size and/or the number of lines to back will need to be increased.

Comment: I see that there is no way to this in an exact manner, i.e., guesswork has to be used. I suspected as much, just wanted to be sure